# Make an OR gate from 2 NAND gates?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates

I have a homework problem on logic gates, in the picture below:

[image]

Now, I have already made NOT and AND gates. On these OR gates, (I used a simulator by the way) I could not find any solution.

I have looked up and found the following picture:

[image]

Though this uses 3 NAND gates, I can only use 2. Remember I can set a fixed value as an input aside from `A` and `B`. **How would I condense 3 NAND gates into 2?**

Comment: Your homework problem, as stated in your question, does not limit you to only 2 NAND gates. It tells you to only use **two-input** NAND gates - in other words, NAND gates with 2 inputs (and implicitly, as many of these two-input NAND gates as you need).

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time. Thanks! :)

Comment: @brhans Your comment effectively answered this question to where the OP was satisfied with it, thus you should post it as an answer. If the OP accepts it this post is effectively closed, though others can add more answers.

Comment: @Sparky256 - yeah - maybe - but it's an answer to an English language comprehension question rather than an electronics one ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are being asked to apply DeMorgan's Theorem to create a positive-logic gate.

More here: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-7/demorgans-theorems/

What you show is fine, they aren't limiting the number of gates you can use.